# Omitting base directories when JARing multiple selective files

Tags: java, class, makefile, jar

I have the following directorie structure:

```
base\
    dir1\
         dir11\
             RequiredFile.class
             NonRequiredFile.class
         dir12\
             AnotherRequiredFile.class
             AnotherNonRequiredFile.class
```

As part of a makefile actions, I would like to archive RequiredFile.class and AnotherRequiredFile.class in the same JAR file, and omit the base/dir directories. The final output should be a single JAR file so that unpacking the JAR file would create the following structure:

```
dir11\
     RequiredFile.class
dir12\
     AnotherRequiredFile.class
```

I know that this can be done using -C flag in the bin/jar command, but it reuqires me to add `-C dir1` before each one of the input file. The above example only contains two, but later there would be more and i wold like to avoid commands such as `jar -C dir FILE -C dir FILE2 -C dir FILE3 ..... -C dir FILEn`

Is there a way to use the  `-C` flag for all input files?

Thanks

Comment: If this is part of a build, (unclear if it is or not), you can accomplish this with Ant: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html or Maven: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html

Comment: I don't know what this has to do with [C] so I am removing that tag

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have all your class files filenames in a Makefile variable already. Provided you are using gnu make, you can then use the `patsubst` function to achieve that:

```
CLASSFILES := RequiredFile.class AnotherRequiredFile.class

DIR := dir1
JAR_CMD = $(patsubst %.class, -C $(DIR) %.class, $(CLASSFILES))
```